# Creating Points from existing data in Rethinkdb

Tags: json, rethinkdb, reql

I'm importing data from a file into Rethinkdb.

the data looks like this (this is fake data)

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Keeley",
    "lastName": "Leannon",
    "createdAt": "2016-05-10T19:55:38.823Z",
    "location": {
      "lat": 52,
      "lng": 0.07687,
      "lastUpdated": "2016-05-16T03:21:25.082Z"
    },
    "company": "Breitenberg and Sons",
    "jobTitle": "Dynamic Group Facilitator",
    "email": "Keeley.Leannon@derrick.com"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Henri",
    "lastName": "Ernser",
    "createdAt": "2016-05-21T11:51:54.581Z",
    "location": {
      "lat": 52,
      "lng": -0.74853,
      "lastUpdated": "2016-04-28T21:15:26.786Z"
    },
    "company": "Gleason, Dickens and Cassin",
    "jobTitle": "Lead Data Consultant",
    "email": "Henri.Ernser@ila.org"
  }
]
```

Now, I want to create [`point`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/point/) objects from the location.lng & location.lat fields, and then remove the lat, and lng fields, so the location field would now look like this

```
 "location": {
          "point": -0.74853, 52,
          "lastUpdated": "2016-04-28T21:15:26.786Z"
        },
```

I'm importing from a file, and as far as i can tell in the docs, there is no way to import directly from a file using ReQL, so i would have to do the import from the command line and then modify each document after the import.

Any pointers on how to go about doing the above?

Answer (score 0):

This command is close enough to what i needed

```
r.db('test').table('people').update(function(item) {
  return {
    location: {
      geometry : r.point(
      item("location")("lng"),
      item("location")("lat")),
      lastUpdated : item("location")("lastUpdated"),
      lat: r.literal(),
      lng: r.literal()
    }
  }
```

})

which results in a location object like

```
    "location": {
        "geometry": {
            "$reql_type$":  "GEOMETRY" ,
             "coordinates": [-0.94645 ,51] ,
             "type":  "Point"
         } ,
         "lastUpdated":  "2016-05-04T01:38:48.786Z"
     }
```